# null pointer exception on SharedPreferences

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

The first time users open my app, `SharedPreferences` might not be created.
So I want to check if `SharedPreferences` has a value or not, and if it has no value (ie `SharedPreferences` has not been created) then create it and set its value.

Here is my code:

```
public static final String PROTECT_STATE = "PROTECT";

@SuppressWarnings("null")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // set/check preference 

    SharedPreferences  protectState = null;
    Editor protectEditor;        

    String isprotectStateSet=protectState.getString("protect_state", "off");
    if(isprotectStateSet == "off"){
        protectState = getSharedPreferences(PROTECT_STATE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        protectEditor=protectState.edit();
        protectEditor.putString("protect_state", "on");
        protectEditor.commit();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I am getting nul pointer exception on the following line.

```
String isprotectStateSet=protectState.getString("protect_state", "off");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to open `SharedPreferences` before reading from them.

move

```
  protectState = getSharedPreferences(PROTECT_STATE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

above this line

```
  String isprotectStateSet=protectState.getString("protect_state", "off");
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
SharedPreferences  protectState = null;
Editor protectEditor;
```

with

```
SharedPreferences  protectState = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor protectEditor = protectState.edit();
```

UPD:

```
isprotectStateSet == "off"
```

It's wrong. Read [this](http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~diam/java/online/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are setting the **protectState** to null then you are trying to **getString** from it while it is null, which is
`SharedPreferences  protectState = null;`